# if-then-else gives a boolean headache

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three statements to combine but I cannot find the correct solution for SQL Server 2008 R2:

I need to concatenate three columns into one but in three different ways depending on the result in the last one. Column 3 can be a null-value, an alphanumeric letter or begin with '-' followed by a number. I tried the following:

```
if (select * from col3  where col3 is null)
 select col1 + ' ' + col2
else if (select * from col3 where col3 like '-%'
 select col1 + ' ' + col2 + col3
else if (select * from col3 where col3 not like '-%'
 select col1 + ' ' + col2 + ' ' + col3
```

Separately, they work like a charm. When trying to combine them like the above statement they throw me an error saying I have created a Boolean instead of the expected condition.

How do I formulate this to be correct?

Answer (score 16):

The syntax you are looking for is the case statement.  You can use `IF .. EXISTS` for controlling the flow in your code but for something like this the `CASE WHEN` statement is what you want.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN col1 + ' ' + col2
    WHEN col3 LIKE '-%' THEN col1 + ' ' + col2 + col3
    WHEN col3 NOT LIKE '-%' THEN col1 + ' ' + col2 + ' ' + col3
    END AS ConcatCol
FROM TableName;
```

and simplified to:

```
SELECT col1 + ' ' + col2 
       + CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN '' 
            WHEN col3 LIKE '-%' THEN col3
            ELSE ' ' + col3
         END AS ConcatCol
FROM TableName;
```

Assuming I understood what you are trying to do of course.

EDIT: Added alias for column

Answer (score 0):

if i'm getting your question correct :

```
         if exists (select 1 from col3 where col3 is null) 
    select col1 + ' ' + col2 from ... where ...
else if exists (select 1 from col3 where col3 like '-%')
    select col1 + ' ' + col2 + col3 from ... where ...
else if exists(select 1 from col3 where col3 not like '-%')
    select col1 + ' ' + col2 + ' ' + col3 from ... where ...
```